# Flink interval join DataStream with KafkaSource drops all records

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**Current Configuration**

- Application runs on Flink 1.14.4
- Within the application, a data stream(result of a long chain of operators) interval joins with a Kafka source.
- Event timestamps per partition are strictly ascending.
- The per-partition watermark strategy on Kafka sets the watermark to the maximum timestamp it has seen so far(bounded-out-of-orderness=1 sec).
- Kafka source(right side of the interval join) by default is around a minute ahead of the other data stream (kafka > datastream)
- Kafka source generates data every 1 minute thus its partitions can be seen as idle for at most 59 seconds. (withIdleness option is not used)

**Problem**

- This setup worked fine until recently where I replaced the deprecated **KafkaConsumer** class with the new **KafkaSource** class.
- The output of the interval join operator should be(and was) the minimum of two incoming streams(Kafka and DS) but with KafkaSource it is set to the maximum after a certain period of time. Thus, all records from the data stream are dropped because its timestamp is behind the watermark(=kafka source).

**Question**

- Does KafkaSource behave differently on window join when stream speeds are not in sync?
- Can watermark of a window join operator be the maximum of the two incoming streams?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue is fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28975. Using KafkaSource with WatermarkWithIdlness has an issue with marking the source as idle status.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to your two questions are "No" and "No".

The new `KafkaSource` does have different watermarking behavior compared to the legacy `FlinkKafkaConsumer` in at least one case: when there are empty partitions. The old source detects empty partitions on startup and automatically marks them as idle, while the new source only detects idle partitions when it is used with the `withIdleness` option.

If you have any empty partitions, this would explain why the join isn't producing any results.

Comment: Hello @David Anderson. I have added a picture describing the problem. Low Watermark of CoGroup is samw as KafkaSource's Low Watermark. Shouldn't it be the minimum of the two incoming streams(Interval Join and DataStream) ?

Comment: I can't explain this; I don't think this should be possible. I would need to see more details to figure out what's going on.