# In what situation can a Flink 1.15.2 job stop consumption on a single Kafka partition, but continue to consume on the other partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

We are running a Flink 1.15.2 cluster with a job that has a Kafka Source and Kafka Sink.

The Source topic has 30 partitions. There are 5 TaskManager nodes with a capacity of 4 slots, and we are running the job with a parallelism of 16, so that is 4 free slots. So depending upon the slots/node assignment, we can expect, each node to have roughly 6-7 partitions assigned.

Our alerting mechanisms notified us that consumer lag was getting built up on a single partition out of the 30 partitions.

As Flink does its own offset management, we had no way of figuring out (through the Flink Web UI or the Kafka console tools) which TaskManager the partition was assigned to.

I would like to know if anyone else has faced this in their experience, and what can be done to proactively monitor and/or mitigate such instances in future. Is it possible for a single partition consumer thread to behave in this manner?

We decided to bounce the Flink TaskManager service one by one hoping that a partition reassignment would jump start consumption again. Bouncing the first node had no impact, but when we bounced the second node, some other TaskManager picked up the lagging partition and started consumption again.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe related to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28975? For more details see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216352/2895401).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the correct explanation, but perhaps [watermark alignment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-182%3A+Support+watermark+alignment+of+FLIP-27+Sources) could explain this sort of behavior.

Comment: We are not using any Watermarking strategy at the moment. Is there anything we can try out that might prevent this situation from happening again? I read your other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101290/2165719 a short while ago.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any theories about what may have caused this. Maybe ask on the flink user mailing list? Others with more Kafka experience might have ideas.

Comment: I'm wondering if checkpointing works as expected, or that there might be data skew that causes checkpointing behaviour to not works as expected.